# Including CSS in Laravel 5 or 4.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

**TL;DR: What is the correct way to link to a stylesheet in Laravel 5?**

**Background:**
I'm using the dev version of Laravel 4.3 (5) because I want to use Socialite, and it makes sense to develop with that from the start. I am having a problem getting templates transferred from 4.2

I've moved my blade layout files to the new directory structure (resources/templates) and placed my CSS in the public/css/ folder.

When I load my route /test/ all I get is "Whoops, looks like something went wrong."

For testing purposes I've removed all blade layout syntax from my layouts - the raw HTML works, but there is no styling (as there is no linked stylesheet). That tells me the routes, views and controllers work.

**The problem:**

In my layouts, if I remove the following, the layouts work:

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

**Question:**

What is the correct location and syntax for Blade Stylesheet inclusion in Laravel 5 and what I should be using instead?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `HtmlBuilder` has been removed from Laravel's core, so `HTML::style()` is no longer available.

If you want to use it in laravel 5, [add the following](https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/html) to your `composer.json` file, under the `require` key:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
```

---

Also note, since `HTML::style()` returns HTML code, you don't want it escaped. Use the raw brackets:

```
{!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Updated my Composer with that, and it works like a charm.

Is there a reason that I shouldn't be using it? Or was it removed simply to give users greater options?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @joseph's answer, for the users preferring not to switch to the new syntax, you can use

```
Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
```

and continue with the old syntax . this can be set almost anywhere, but a better choice would be a service provider, say legacy service provide for l4 . you can find further discussion on this at [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/new-blade-tag-for-unescaped-data-thoughts), where you can find taylor otwells thoughts on this .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain HTML then use like this-

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/folder/style.css">
```