# Laravel 5 issues with linking css assets

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5

am currently trying to port my laravel 4 application to laravel 5  . i have added `"illuminate/html": "5.*"` to composer and also the facade and service providers to config.  i was using the following syntax to link to my css files

```
{{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

but in laravel 5 , my views output is all broken , with the page displaying like the below screenshot .

[image: laravel blade issue.]

what could i be missing here ? is there any changes to the blade syntax in laravel 5 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including CSS in Lavavel 5 or 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714910/including-css-in-lavavel-5-or-4-3)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found the answer here on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27714910/including-css-in-lavavel-5-or-4-3) and [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/new-blade-tag-for-unescaped-data-thoughts) .
on the second thread Taylor Otwell gives the answer himself . In laravel 5 , the laravel 4 default syntax `{{ code }}` , will escape the data output . if you want unescaped html data, you have to use the new syntax

```
{!! HTML::style('css/style.css') !!}
```

if you want to revert to previous syntax you can use

```
Blade::setRawTags('{{', '}}');
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Check if the assets are there, and are being linked properly.
2. check permission and set `chmod` to 777 (Unix).
3. If that doesn't work, use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('relative/to/public/folder.css')}}" >` manually.

Comment: found out it has to do with the new laravel 5 syntax . for unescaped data output need to use  {!! !!}

Answer (score 4):

```
<link href="{{ asset("assets/css/style.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code to the below

```
{!! Html::style( asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')) !!}
{!! Html::style( asset('css/style.css')) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain HTML then you can also use it like this-

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```