# Laravel-5.3 use without artisan serve command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan, serve

I have a problem about laravel run without use php artisan serve command. I'm working in xampp/htdocs/works folder. I created a blog under htdocs/works folder and if i use php artisan not problem but i want to use without php artisan like localhost:8080/works/blog/ working but not find css and js files.

How can I solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

The first place I would check is the resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php or any other views you are trying to access and make sure it use a relative path like:

```
<link href="/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The root is /public for the path, so in this example, app.css should be in public/css/app.css

Hope this help.

Comment: The port should not affect the path of your files, what is the href of your css files in resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php ? Maybe you could take a look to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727744/laravel-5-issues-with-linking-css-assets

Comment: not working. please help me with a video from start to end use without php artisan . please help

Answer (score 0):

you can use the helper asset

```
<link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

here the official doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-asset

Answer (score 0):

The best soulution which works every time, is using [Elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir)

Read the documentation, you can insert your files like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ elixir('css/all.css') }}">
<script src="{{ elixir('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

I recomend starting with Webpack.